# How do you end all processes called by a shell file

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

Okay, so I have a dilemma that I've been staring at for too long. I tried most online solutions but they just haven't worked very well...

I have a shell file. Let's called it "a". "a" looks a lot like this:

```
#a.sh

sh b.sh &
sh c.sh &
```

b.sh and c.sh look a lot like this:

```
#b.sh
run a process
run this opensource software over these files and wait
if condition; do
    sh e.sh
else
    f.sh
fi
```

And then c.sh:

```
#c.sh
call some other programs
call some python files
call these shell files
... etc
```

Of course, `f.sh` and `e.sh` are similar and run their own processes and stuff.

Now, as you can see, when I run "a.sh", it runs a myriad of other things. I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, and the processes are still running in the background. I close the terminal; same thing. I tried to kill with ID but I just don't know how to do it for a lot of the open source software I am using. Specifically, I have, for example tried [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618403/how-to-kill-all-subprocesses-of-shell), but how do I make `a.sh` know the different processes being run in e.sh and so on so it can kill them? It hasn't been working I tell you.

Is there a command that lets me end all processes started by a shell file? I know this is *so* annoying but I cannot share the code as of right now. If you really need me to, I can post something that looks similar, but again, a lot of what I am doing is running software based on certain conditions and the software and shell files don't close when I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. So I am forced to `pkill -U myuser`, but this is impractical.

Comment: Possible:  https://serverfault.com/questions/72212/possible-to-send-kill-signal-to-all-processes-with-a-given-ppid  My guess is that when you launch the script it will have a PID and then the subscripts would have their own PID, but should belong to the PPID of the first script.  Looking at `ps -ef` should show the PPID.

Comment: Reformulate the problem: [how to find all processes descended from a given process](https://superuser.com/questions/363169/ps-how-can-i-recursively-get-all-child-process-for-a-given-pid).

Answer (score 2):

If `pstree $(pgrep a)` lists all the descendant processes of `a` you can send `SIGTERM` to all of them (includig `a.sh`) with:

```
kill $(pstree -p $(pgrep "a.sh") | awk -F"[)(]" '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=2)print $i}')
```

If that's not the case and neither `kill -$(pgrep a)` (notice the `-`) nor `pkill -P $(pgrep a)` can help I suggest you add a line to the beginning of the scripts and append its PID to a single file like this:

```
echo $$ >>/path/to/the/pidfile
```

This way you always have a list of PIDs available to kill with a simple:

```
kill </path/to/the/pidfile
```

Comment: Yeah, this was what I had to do. I wanted a more "bash" looking method, but unfortunately beggars cannot be choosers :(